# F2 Rename Symbol in VSCode does not work with Apex

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code

I am unable to get the `Rename Symbol` F2 command to work in VSCode when editing a Apex class.

When I press `F2` the floating input appears, once I press enter the code is not updated, and I cannot see any errors.

According to the documentation this should work?

- [Apex Refactoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/refactoring)

**Questions:**

1. what am I doing wrong?
2. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/refactoring

[image]

It's actually hard to see in the .gif they provided in the link (tried to screengrab the moment and included above), but you have to highlight the **whole word** you're looking to rename as opposed to simply clicking your cursor on it.

Once you've highlighted the name in question, you can simply click F2 or right click and select "rename symbol".